# SSL directory structure

Tags: php, apache, ssl, directory, structure

I've got a web app and now I've been told to implement SSL for that. I've never done that before, but I seem to have understood from Internet docs on how to do that.

But, my app has two sides: the user interface which is fine under SSL and the second side is I have some files that need to bypass the certificate. These files are accessed by remote machines and share the same libraries of some user interface files.

I've managed the bypass using symbolic links for the shared libraries but I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it. I mean, if I don't use symbolic links to the shared libraries I can't use these scripts.

Thanks in advance for any light!

Comment: What do you mean by "bypass the certificate" are you using a different client for the user interface and those files?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are calling the web pages from another machine but you want to bypass the cert? You can usually use curl for this: curl --no-check-certificate {url}

Otherwise you can probably just call those files without the 's' in the scheme (https / http) and be fine.

Comment: I have remote machines that ask from time to time for a rss schedule from the server. But curl seem to be an option. I'm going to try it and let you know! Many Thanks!